# IE8 is appending when using jQuery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, toggle

My co-worker and I have spent about an hour on this now and we can't figure it out. This works fine for us in Chrome and Firefox. This is basically a dumbed down version of it:

http://jsbin.com/osebuc

It works fine in this test case, but in IE8 on our real thing it's appending the HTML. We literally just have `$('.panda').html(someHtml)` in the code, but in IE, instead of replacing the HTML it appends the HTML each time.

We also tried `$('.panda').empty().html(someHtml)` in IE, but then IE seems to "lose track" of `.panda` and doing a `console.log($('.panda').length)` returns `1`, then another button click (back to the original HTML), returns `0`.

Has anyone else seen this? Anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

**Why:**
My co-worker and I are trying to make some forms look prettier (beta form) without touching the original HTML (we can't) but have a way to go back to the original form (classic) if they click a button. To do this we cache the original HTML in a var, then we build the new, beta HTML, save it to a var, and then do the example above in a toggle.

Comment: I can't reproduce on IE9 with IE8 emulated.

Comment: Like i said, _"It works fine in this test case, but in IE8 on our real thing it's appending the HTML."_ I wasn't sure if anyone else came into this problem and has any idea of why this _would_ happen.

Comment: Some old versions of IE have had issues with cloning DOM elements. Perhaps that's the problem here. Could you circumvent the problem by hiding one DIV and showing another?

Comment: Try replacing your class with an ID and see if that solves things.

Comment: Awh, maybe that'd work. Never even thought about showing/hiding, mblase75. I'll try that out.

Comment: I've seen DOM manipulation do weird stuff in IE when you have tags and aren't closed properly and the like.  I'd double-check that your markup is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the very same issue:   `.html()` in IE7 / IE8 was appending.

I managed to sort it by doing the following:

```
$('panda').html("").html(someHtml);
```

Basically, manually set it to blank, and then add the code from the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Although, I persnally prefer jQuery, have you tried plain-old javascript?

```
$('.panda')[0].innerHTML = "";
$('.panda')[0].innerHTML = "some html";
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. Be sure your HTML is valid. I had a different open and closing tag ^^